# How to add section at the top of second section html css?

Tags: html, css

I Want To Put the `search-from` at the top of the second section `section seller-listings`

Like this

[image]

Here is my search-form and the grey color is coming at the top:

[image]

I have tried giving `position:absoulte` to the `search-block` but it looks like this

[image]

Here is my **Html Code** :

**Full Code**

```
<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navigation">
                        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                            <img src="images/site-logo.png">
                        </a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto main-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Buy bitcoins</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sell bitcoins</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Post a trade</a>
                                </li>                                                               
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-10">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link login-button" href="#">Log In</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link register-button" href="#">Register</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>                           
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Hero -->
    <section class="hero text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content-block">
                <h1>Buy and sell bitcoins near you</h1>
                <h2>Instant. Secure. Private.</h2>
                <h4 class="mb-4">Trade bitcoins in <span>7824 cities</span> and <span>248 countries</span> including <span>Pakistan.</span></h4>
                <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign up free</a>
            </div>  

            <!-- Search -->
            <div class="search-block">
                <div class="search-form">
                    <form>
                        <div class="inner-form">    
                            <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                                <input class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Amount">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                                <select class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                                    <option>PKR</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field third-wrap">
                                <select class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                                    <option>Pakistan</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                </select>                   
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field fouth-wrap">
                                <select class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                                    <option>All online offers</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                    <option>Example</option>
                                </select>                   
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field fifth-wrap">
                                <button class="btn-search" type="button">Search</button>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>  
    </section>

    <section class="seller-listings section bg-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead class="black white-text">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">#</th>
                      <th scope="col">First</th>
                      <th scope="col">Last</th>
                      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                      <td>Mark</td>
                      <td>Otto</td>
                      <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">2</th>
                      <td>Jacob</td>
                      <td>Thornton</td>
                      <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">3</th>
                      <td>Larry</td>
                      <td>the Bird</td>
                      <td>@twitter</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

> **Edit**

I fixed the problem by giving the `search-block` `position: relative`.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to specifically move the search area to inside the gray area right on top of the table?

Comment: provide any working section like pluker or js fiddle

Comment: Post all of your code and maybe we can help more!

Comment: @AlexandreLage the search area is the part of hero section. I want the search area at the top of the section below

Comment: @Glen Question Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone face the same problem. you can fix this by adding postion: realtive;

```
.search-block {
  position: relative;
}
```

And it'll come at the top:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I have added the bootstrap classes. You may edit the CSS and content for the table accordingly.

```
<section class="hero text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-block">
      <h1>Buy and sell bitcoins near you</h1>
      <h2>Instant. Secure. Private.</h2>
      <h4 class="mb-4">
        Trade bitcoins in <span>7824 cities</span> and
        <span>248 countries</span> including <span>Pakistan.</span>
      </h4>
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign up free</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Search -->
    <div class="search-block">
      <div class="search-form">
        <form>
          <div class="inner-form row">
            <div class="input-field first-wrap col">
              <input
                class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"
                id="search"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Amount"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field second-wrap col">
              <select class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                <option>PKR</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field third-wrap col">
              <select class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                <option>Pakistan</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field fouth-wrap col">
              <select class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                <option>All online offers</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
                <option>Example</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field fifth-wrap col">
              <button class="btn-search" type="button">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          </table>
        </form>
        <table class="row">
          <tr class="col-3">
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="col-3">
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="col-3">
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="col-3">
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is lacking here

Comment: It's not html fault it's css fault he need to change css not html